# how to insert values in a particular column using list

Tags: java, list, addition

A table of 3 columns, dynamically increase the size of rows and insert values in a particular column of a selected row.

I'm able to increase the row size and also insert in a particular column using list but the previously entered column value disappears and the new one appears at the correct location.

Note: database is not used all the values are stored in List.

```
List<Checkpointclass> addchk = List<Checkpointclass>)request.getServletContext().getAttribute("stageattr");

for(Checkpointclass add:addchk)
{
  System.out.println(stage + "&" + add.getStage());
  if(add.getStage().equals(stage)){
    add.setCheckpoint(checkpoint);//3 columns
    add.setStage(stage);//row
    add.setRunway(runway);//id of those 3 columns
  }
}  
request.getRequestDispatcher( "GEFP.jsp" ).forward(request,response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not inserting a new element. You are modifying an existing one.

If you wish to add a new element to the list, you should first find the index where you want to add the element, and then create a new element and add it :

```
        for(int i=0; i<addchk.length; i++)
        {
            Checkpointclass add = addchk.get(i);
            System.out.println(stage + "&" + add.getStage());
            if(add.getStage().equals(stage)){
                break;
            }
        }
        Checkpointclass newadd = new Checkpointclass ();
        newadd.setCheckpoint(checkpoint);//3 columns
        newadd.setStage(stage);//row
        newadd.setRunway(runway);//id of those 3 columns  
        addchk.add(i,newadd);
```

Comment: actually its like modifying because while adding a new row all the three columns will be null. so its like modifying the null into a value.

Comment: @user3724845 I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Did you want to modify an existing element of the list? In that case, which value disappeared?

Comment: |      | column1 | column2 | column3 |
| row1 | value1.1|         |         |
| row2 | value2.1|         |         |

as above if I'm entering values in the first column it is displaying all the values in that column alone. but if i try to enter a different column say column2then the value in column1 goes off.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand where you are blocking:

```
Checkpointclass cp = new Checkpointclass();
cp.setCheckPoint("...");
cp.setStage("...");
cp.setRunway("...");
addchk.add(cp);
```

And don't do the `add` while iterating over the `addchck`, you would only get a [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html). For that, you'll need a new copy of the list or temporize the new item additions.